# Auto adjust column width upon hiding other column using bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to bootstrap. I have two divs, one has `.col-9` css and another div has `.col-3` css.

So upon hiding the `.col-3` div, I want that 1st div to become `.col-12` or in some other manner auto-adjust to that width.

This is the code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div  class="col-md-9"> **<!--div 1-->**
        <div class="panel panel-danger ">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <button class="btn btn-danger ">Delete</button>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <button class="btn btn-default margin_btn" > Sunglasses <i class="fa fa-close fa_elec " ></i></button>
                <button class="btn btn-default margin_btn" > Fragrances <i class="fa fa-close fa_elec " ></i></button>
                <button class="btn btn-default margin_btn" > Watches <i class="fa fa-close fa_elec " ></i></button>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div  class="col-md-3" ng-hide="true"> **<!--div 2-->**
        <div class="panel panel-danger ">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <button class="btn btn-danger ">Delete</button>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <button class="btn btn-default margin_btn" > Sunglasses <i class="fa fa-close fa_elec " ></i></button>
                <button class="btn btn-default margin_btn" > Fragrances <i class="fa fa-close fa_elec " ></i></button>
                <button class="btn btn-default margin_btn" > Watches <i class="fa fa-close fa_elec " ></i></button>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ng-class="{'col-md-9': isHiding != true}"  ng-class="{'col-md-12': isHiding == true}"

you can use in this way..

Answer (score 2):

Add IDs to the columns and do something like so:

```
$('#button').click(function(){
   $('#3col').hide();
   $('#9col').removeClass("col-md-9").addClass("col-md-12");
});
```